# Cannot read property "classList" of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a facebook clone and 'm facing a problem in see more button it shows the hidden items on first click but does not hide them on another click also on each click it gives the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined"

My javascript code

```js
function showHidden() {
            // i = 0;
            let items = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
            if (items[0].classList.contains("hidden")) {
                for (i = 0; items.length > 0; i++) {
                    items[i].classList.add("unhidden");
                }
            } else if (items[0].classList.contains("unhidden") && items[0].classList.contains("hidden")) {
                for (i = 0; items.length > 0; i++) {
                    items[i].classList.remove("unhidden");
                }
            }
        }
```

My HTML Code

```html
<li class="unhidden"><img
                    src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/71/fc/47/71fc472790aa43f44555d08f4d4904c2.jpg"><a
                    href="#"><b>MR. X</b></a></li>
            <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yx/r/5rR6LRpNc5u.png"><a
                    href="#"><b>Covid 19 Information
                        Center</b></a></li>
            <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y8/r/S0U5ECzYUSu.png"><a
                    href="#"><b>Friends</b></a></li>
            <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yU/r/D2y-jJ2C_hO.png"><a
                    href="#"><b>Market Place</b></a>
            </li>
            <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y9/r/DHBHg9MEeSC.png"><a
                    href="#"><b>Ads</b></a></li>
            <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y5/r/duk32h44Y31.png"><a
                    href="#"><b>Watch</b></a></li>
            <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y8/r/he-BkogidIc.png"><a
                    href="#"><b>Memories</b></a>
            </li>
            <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y5/r/PrjLkDYpYbH.png"><a
                    href="#"><b>Groups</b></a></li>
            <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a
                    href="#"><b>Events</b></a></li>
            <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a
                    href="#"><b></b></a></li>
            <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a
                    href="#"><b></b></a></li>
            <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a
                    href="#"><b></b></a></li>
            <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a
                    href="#"><b></b></a></li>
            <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a
                    href="#"><b></b></a></li>
            <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a
                    href="#"><b></b></a></li>
            <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a
                    href="#"><b></b></a></li>
            <li class="unhidden" onclick="showHidden();"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i><a href="#"
                    style="padding-left: 21px;"><b>See More</b></a></li>
```

CSS :

```css
#navbarHz {
    /* position: fixed; */
    top: 3rem;
    /* top: 0; */
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

#navbarHz>ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 22vw;
    flex-direction: column;
    list-style: none;
    /* height: auto; */
    /* overflow-y: auto; */
}

#navbarHz>ul>li {
    padding: 10px;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>i{
    /* width: 40px; */
    /* margin-left: 12px; */
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    display: block;
    /* margin-left: 12px; */
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
#navbarHz>ul>li>img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
```

Comment: `for ( i = 0; items.length > 0; i++ ) {` what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is because of wrong logic in the `for` statement.

You have used

```
for (i = 0; items.length > 0; i++) {
```

***This will result in an infinte loop***

which will always true if `items.length` is not equal to `0`. So when `i > items.length` then it will be undefined and getting `classList` on `undefined` will produce error.

```
for ( i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
```

```js
function showHidden() {
  // i = 0;
  let items = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
  if (items[0].classList.contains("hidden")) {
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].classList.add("unhidden");
    }
  } else if (items[0].classList.contains("unhidden") && items[0].classList.contains("hidden")) {
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      items[i].classList.remove("unhidden");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#navbarHz {
  /* position: fixed; */
  top: 3rem;
  /* top: 0; */
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#navbarHz>ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 22vw;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  /* height: auto; */
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
}

#navbarHz>ul>li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>i {
  /* width: 40px; */
  /* margin-left: 12px; */
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: block;
  /* margin-left: 12px; */
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<li class="unhidden"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/71/fc/47/71fc472790aa43f44555d08f4d4904c2.jpg"><a href="#"><b>MR. X</b></a></li>
<li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yx/r/5rR6LRpNc5u.png"><a href="#"><b>Covid 19 Information Center</b></a></li>
<li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y8/r/S0U5ECzYUSu.png"><a href="#"><b>Friends</b></a></li>
<li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yU/r/D2y-jJ2C_hO.png"><a href="#"><b>Market Place</b></a></li>
<li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y9/r/DHBHg9MEeSC.png"><a href="#"><b>Ads</b></a></li>
<li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y5/r/duk32h44Y31.png"><a href="#"><b>Watch</b></a></li>
<li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y8/r/he-BkogidIc.png"><a href="#"><b>Memories</b></a></li>
<li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y5/r/PrjLkDYpYbH.png"><a href="#"><b>Groups</b></a></li>
<li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b>Events</b></a></li>
<li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
<li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
<li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
<li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
<li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
<li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
<li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png" class="hidden"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
<li class="unhidden" onclick="showHidden();"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i><a href="#" style="padding-left: 21px;"><b>See More</b></a></li>
```

**------------EDITED-------------**

```js
function showHidden() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
#navbarHz {
  /* position: fixed; */
  top: 3rem;
  /* top: 0; */
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#navbarHz>ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 22vw;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  /* height: auto; */
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
}

#navbarHz>ul>li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>i {
  /* width: 40px; */
  /* margin-left: 12px; */
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: block;
  /* margin-left: 12px; */
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.unhidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbarHz">
  <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/71/fc/47/71fc472790aa43f44555d08f4d4904c2.jpg"><a href="#"><b>MR. X</b></a></li>
  <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yx/r/5rR6LRpNc5u.png"><a href="#"><b>Covid 19 Information Center</b></a></li>
  <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y8/r/S0U5ECzYUSu.png"><a href="#"><b>Friends</b></a></li>
  <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yU/r/D2y-jJ2C_hO.png"><a href="#"><b>Market Place</b></a></li>
  <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y9/r/DHBHg9MEeSC.png"><a href="#"><b>Ads</b></a></li>
  <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y5/r/duk32h44Y31.png"><a href="#"><b>Watch</b></a></li>
  <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y8/r/he-BkogidIc.png"><a href="#"><b>Memories</b></a></li>
  <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y5/r/PrjLkDYpYbH.png"><a href="#"><b>Groups</b></a></li>
  <li class="unhidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b>Events</b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="unhidden" onclick="showHidden();"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i><a href="#" style="padding-left: 21px;"><b>See More</b></a></li>

</div>
```

---

**Edited to toggle `see more` and `hide`**

```js
function showHidden() {
  let hidden = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
  let unHidden = document.querySelectorAll(".unhidden");
  let btn = document.querySelector(".see-more-btn").querySelector("a").firstElementChild;

  if (hidden.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
      hidden[i].classList.remove("hidden");
      hidden[i].classList.add("unhidden");
      btn.textContent = "Hide"
    }
  } else if (unHidden.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < unHidden.length; i++) {
      unHidden[i].classList.remove("unhidden");
      unHidden[i].classList.add("hidden");
      btn.textContent = "See More"
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#navbarHz {
  /* position: fixed; */
  top: 3rem;
  /* top: 0; */
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#navbarHz>ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 22vw;
  flex-direction: column;
  list-style: none;
  /* height: auto; */
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
}

#navbarHz>li {
  padding: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>i {
  /* width: 40px; */
  /* margin-left: 12px; */
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: block;
  /* margin-left: 12px; */
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#navbarHz>ul>li>img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbarHz">
  <li><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/71/fc/47/71fc472790aa43f44555d08f4d4904c2.jpg"><a href="#"><b>MR. X</b></a></li>
  <li><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yx/r/5rR6LRpNc5u.png"><a href="#"><b>Covid 19 Information Center</b></a></li>
  <li><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y8/r/S0U5ECzYUSu.png"><a href="#"><b>Friends</b></a></li>
  <li><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yU/r/D2y-jJ2C_hO.png"><a href="#"><b>Market Place</b></a></li>
  <li><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y9/r/DHBHg9MEeSC.png"><a href="#"><b>Ads</b></a></li>
  <li><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y5/r/duk32h44Y31.png"><a href="#"><b>Watch</b></a></li>
  <li><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y8/r/he-BkogidIc.png"><a href="#"><b>Memories</b></a></li>
  <li><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/y5/r/PrjLkDYpYbH.png"><a href="#"><b>Groups</b></a></li>
  <li><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b>Events</b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li class="hidden"><img src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/ys/r/8wTx0Eu2vRq.png"><a href="#"><b></b></a></li>
  <li onclick="showHidden();" class="see-more-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <a href="#" style="padding-left: 21px;">
      <b>See More</b>
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please give the correct js code ? ... js is not my cup of tea neither i am too good at it

Comment: It sholuld be `for ( i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) {`

Comment: its not hiding the elements again just showing it once

Comment: @OmNigam There might be some other problem in the code. But what you have asked is answered and that was because of `for` wrong logic

Comment: btw what are you trying to do here, let me help you...

Comment: just like in the facebook web version i am trying to hide and unhide the elements on show more button click

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235011/discussion-between-om-nigam-and-decpk).

Comment: Let's avoid extended discussion in comments

Comment: please tell if there is any way to hide the elements too on click

Comment: @OmNigam Edited again. Hope this is what you want...

Comment: yup it worked can u also tell how may i change the inner html of the see more li to see less when the content is unhidden and to see more when the content is hidden

Comment: That part is also added to the code. I've used `Hide` instead of `See less`. Please see the code

Comment: can you please explain me what you did in the dicussion

Comment: i mean how did you manage to hide and unhide also toggle too